# Observable is causing memory leak - Angular / Ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm able to get GPS - lat and long. The issue is, the device is trying to get a GPS reading every second from ionic native geolocation foreground tracking. I'm using both geolocation and background geolocation. The issue is my watch position on the geolocation is running until I unsubscribe (which makes sense). Maybe this is trivial and I'm over thinking but I should be able to unsubscribe right after I subscribe to watch position and retrieve that data correct? Wrong. I'm not able to even read a console.log message inside of the subscription if that's the case. I'm unsubscribing from watch in the stop tracking but I'm still getting a console message of the GPS data every second until stop tracking is hit, which is every 30 seconds. thanks - Ionic 3

map.ts

```
startTracking() {

    console.log('started tracking')
    const config: BackgroundGeolocationConfig = {
      desiredAccuracy: 10,
      stationaryRadius: 20,
      distanceFilter: 30,
      debug: false, //  enable this hear sounds for background-geolocation life-cycle.
      stopOnTerminate: false
  };

  this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config)
  .subscribe((location: BackgroundGeolocationResponse) => {

  console.log('location', location, location.bearing, location.speed, location.longitude);

  this.zone.run(() => {
    this.lat = location.latitude
    this.lng = location.longitude
    this.bearing = location.bearing
    this.speed = location.speed
    this.accuracy = location.accuracy
    this.timestamp = location.time
  })


  this.backgroundGeolocation.finish(); // FOR IOS ONLY

  });

//foreground tracking 

  let options: GeolocationOptions = {
    timeout: 300000,
    enableHighAccuracy: true
  };

  this.watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition(options).filter((p: any) => p.code === undefined).subscribe((position: Geoposition) => {

     console.log(position);

     // Run update inside of Angular's zone
     this.zone.run(() => {
       this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
       this.lng = position.coords.longitude;
       this.speed = position.coords.speed;
       this.accuracy = position.coords.accuracy
     });

     console.log(this.lat, this.lng , 'this is the lat lng')
   });

  this.backgroundGeolocation.start();
  }

getGPSData(){

this.gpsunsub = this.service.sendGPS(GPSobjectshere).subscribe(result => {

          }

        }


}

stopTracking() {
  this.backgroundGeolocation.stop();
  console.log('stopped tracking')
  this.watch.unsubscribe();
  this.getGPSData()
  this.gpsunsub.unsubscribe()  
 }
```

app.component.ts

```
constructor(){
 this.sendGPSStart()
 this.interval()
}

sendGPSStart(){
    this.locationTracker.startTracking();
  }

  sendGPSStop(){
    this.locationTracker.stopTracking();
}

interval(){
setInterval(() => {
       this.sendGPSStart()
          this.sendGPSStop()
    }, '30000')

}
```

Comment: Why don't you try to stop the tracking inside the callback method of start watch position function? Current code doesn't seems correct. You are calling stop tracking method immediately after the start tracking method, it seems that even before the subscription is initialized you are trying to unsubscribe as there is no time delay between those two function calls.